# Create service Java spring ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, spring, ubuntu

how to create Linux service Java spring ?

This is my `/etc/systemd/system/javatest.service` config

```
[Unit]
Description=A Spring Boot application
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=baeldung
ExecStart= /usr/bin/java jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev provider-integration-api.jar -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
SuccessExitStatus = 143    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This not working but this 2 config working , how to start with java options ?

**This Working**

```
[Unit]
    Description=A Spring Boot application
    After=syslog.target
    
    [Service]
    User=baeldung
    ExecStart=/opt/Java-provider-api/provider-integration-api.jar 
    jcSuccessExitStatus=143 
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should looks like: 
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector provider-integration-api.jar`

Pay attention on:

- you should use `-jar` and not `jar`
- [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#CBBIJCHG) (system properties in your case, which start from `-D`) should be put before the .jar file; if you will put something after .jar file it will be taken as an arguments

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).